# Angular2 Typescript Full Calendar Context Menu

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, fullcalendar, contextmenu

I have an angular2 app using typescript which contains an instance of the FullCalendar component. On this component, i have it working so that the events are coloured by their "Table" (a resource), click an event to view the event page and drag an event to change the date. This all works perfectly. However, now what i want to do is to create functionality to alter the "Table" the event is assigned to. My thoughts on this were to have a context menu attached to it where you can right click and select a new "Table" but i cannot work out how to do this on Full Calendar.

Does anybody have any ideas or examples?

I would also be open to using other events. Obviously i have already used the click and drop events but if theres another im missing that may be suitable i am open to it.

Here is my code for my calendar at the moment:

```
this.scheduleService.GetAllEvents()
                        .subscribe((data: CalendarEvent[]) => { 
                            this.events = data;
                            var calendar: JQuery = $("#calendar");
                            (<any>calendar).fullCalendar({
                                events: data,
                                eventOrder: "Table",
                                height: 800,
                                weekends: false,
                                eventLimit: true,
                                eventClick: function(event) {
                                    window.open(event.url);
                                    return false;
                                },
                                editable:true,
                                eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                                    if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                                        revertFunc();
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        service.UpdatePlannedCompletion(event.title.substring(0,1), event.start.format())
                                                .subscribe((data: number) => console.log(data));
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Assuming this is what you meant by your unhelpful link...i have added my current full calendar code